# Indicator not working properly - calculates high / low for certain time ranges

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have been working on a script for an indicator that will plot on the chart the high and low for a certain timerange. For example - London Session - kill zone:  02:00 - 05:00

For some reason when you switch to a different timezone the script doesn't work properly. It doesn't show the proper timeranges or the high and low. It looks like the script only works for a certain number of bars back. The smaller the timeframe (form 15 min down to 1 min) the worse it gets. The thing that changes is the number of bars. I think I do something wrong here. Please help to improve the script please!

I want it to work for at least two weeks back on a 1 min timeframe.  The code used is shown beneath:

```
indicator('BTB', 'Liquidity', overlay=true, max_bars_back = 500, explicit_plot_zorder=true)

exchange_timezone_correction = input.int(defval = 7, minval = 0, maxval=23, title="Time difference for exchange timezone in hours", group="Start", inline="Timezone Correction")
//LDN Session Range
range_start_hour_LDN = input.int(defval=9, minval=0, maxval=23, title="Start Hour LDN Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_start_minute_LDN = input.int(defval=0, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes LDN Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_end_hour_LDN = input.int(defval=12, minval=0, maxval=23, title="End Hour LDN Session", group="END", inline="end")
range_end_minute_LDN = input.int(defval=0, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes LDN Session", group="END", inline="end")

//NY AM Session Range
range_start_hour_AM = input.int(defval=16, minval=0, maxval=23, title="Start AM Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_start_minute_AM = input.int(defval=30, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes AM Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_end_hour_AM = input.int(defval=19, minval=0, maxval=23, title="End Hour AM Session", group="END", inline="end")
range_end_minute_AM = input.int(defval=0, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes AM Sesion", group="END", inline="end")

//NY PM Range
range_start_hour_Lunch = input.int(defval=19, minval=0, maxval=23, title="Start Hour NY Lunch", group="START", inline="start")
range_start_minute_Lunch = input.int(defval=00, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes NY Lunch", group="START", inline="start")
range_end_hour_Lunch = input.int(defval=20, minval=0, maxval=23, title="End Hour NY Lunch", group="END", inline="end")
range_end_minute_Lunch = input.int(defval=30, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes NY Lunch", group="END", inline="end")

//NY PM Session Range
range_start_hour_PM = input.int(defval=20, minval=0, maxval=23, title="Start PM Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_start_minute_PM = input.int(defval=30, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes PM Session", group="START", inline="start")
range_end_hour_PM = input.int(defval=23, minval=0, maxval=23, title="End Hour PM Session", group="END", inline="end")
range_end_minute_PM = input.int(defval=0, minval=0, maxval=59, title="Minutes PM Sesion", group="END", inline="end")

//Input for lay our on chart
colorTop = input(color.green)
colorBottom = input(color.red)
colorMid = input(color.purple)
colorSession = input(color.blue)
close_to_close = input(false, "Close To Close (instead of low to high distance)")
Equilibrium = input(true,"Do you want to see te PD Array of the session")

//Range London Session
isInRange_LDN = (hour*60 + minute<= (range_end_hour_LDN*60+range_end_minute_LDN) and hour*60 + minute > range_start_minute_LDN+range_start_hour_LDN*60)
isOnEnd_LDN = (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_end_hour_LDN*60+range_end_minute_LDN and hour*60 + minute >= range_end_hour_LDN*60+range_end_minute_LDN)
isOnStart_LDN =(hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_start_minute_LDN+range_start_hour_LDN*60 and hour*60 + minute >= range_start_minute_LDN+range_start_hour_LDN*60)
//Range AM Session
isInRange_AM = (hour*60 + minute<= (range_end_hour_AM*60+range_end_minute_AM) and hour*60 + minute > range_start_minute_AM+range_start_hour_AM*60) 
isOnEnd_AM = (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_end_hour_AM*60+range_end_minute_AM and hour*60 + minute >= range_end_hour_AM*60+range_end_minute_AM)
isOnStart_AM =  (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_start_minute_AM+range_start_hour_AM*60 and hour*60 + minute >= range_start_minute_AM+range_start_hour_AM*60)
//Range Lunch NY
isInRange_Lunch = (hour*60 + minute<= (range_end_hour_Lunch*60+range_end_minute_Lunch) and hour*60 + minute > range_start_minute_Lunch+range_start_hour_Lunch*60)
isOnEnd_Lunch = (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_end_hour_Lunch*60+range_end_minute_Lunch and hour*60 + minute >= range_end_hour_Lunch*60+range_end_minute_Lunch)
isOnStart_Lunch = (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_start_minute_Lunch+range_start_hour_Lunch*60 and hour*60 + minute >= range_start_minute_Lunch+range_start_hour_Lunch*60)
//Range PM Session
isInRange_PM = (hour*60 + minute<= (range_end_hour_PM*60+range_end_minute_PM) and hour*60 + minute > range_start_minute_PM+range_start_hour_PM*60) 
isOnEnd_PM = (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_end_hour_PM*60+range_end_minute_PM and hour*60 + minute >= range_end_hour_PM*60+range_end_minute_PM)
isOnStart_PM =  (hour[1]*60 + minute[1] < range_start_minute_PM+range_start_hour_PM*60 and hour*60 + minute >= range_start_minute_PM+range_start_hour_PM*60)

var startIDX_LDN = -1
var startIDX_AM = -1
var startIDX_Lunch = -1
var startIDX_PM = -1

var range_high_LDN = -100000.0
var range_low_LDN = 99999999.9
var range_mid_LDN = 0.0
var range_high_AM = -100000.0
var range_low_AM = 99999999.9
var range_mid_AM = 0.0
var range_high_Lunch = -100000.0
var range_low_Lunch = 99999999.9
var range_mid_Lunch = 0.0
var range_high_PM = -100000.0
var range_low_PM = 99999999.9
var range_mid_PM = 0.0

var distance_LDN = 1.0
var distance_AM = 1.0
var distance_Lunch = 1.0
var distance_PM = 1.0

//Code for drawing Top and Bottom Range London Session
if isOnStart_LDN
    startIDX_LDN:=bar_index

if isInRange_LDN
    line.new(startIDX_LDN,close,startIDX_LDN,close,extend = extend.both,color=colorSession)
    if not close_to_close
        range_high_LDN := math.max(range_high_LDN, high)
        range_low_LDN:= math.min(range_low_LDN, low)
    
    if close_to_close
        range_high_LDN := math.max(range_high_LDN, close)
        range_low_LDN:= math.min(range_low_LDN, close)
    distance_LDN := range_high_LDN - range_low_LDN
    if Equilibrium
        range_mid_LDN := range_high_LDN - distance_LDN/2

if isOnEnd_LDN
    line.new(startIDX_LDN, range_mid_LDN, bar_index, range_mid_LDN, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_dotted, color=colorMid,width =2)
    line.new(startIDX_LDN, range_high_LDN, bar_index, range_high_LDN, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorTop,width =2)
    var label_LDN_High = label.new(bar_index,range_high_LDN,text="BSL LDN",textcolor=colorTop,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_LDN_High,(startIDX_LDN+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_LDN_High,range_high_LDN)
    label.set_size(label_LDN_High,size.normal)
    line.new(startIDX_LDN, range_low_LDN, bar_index, range_low_LDN, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorBottom,width =2)
    var label_LDN_Low = label.new(bar_index,range_low_LDN,text="SSL LDN",textcolor=colorBottom,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_LDN_Low,(startIDX_LDN+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_LDN_Low,range_low_LDN)
    label.set_size(label_LDN_Low,size.normal)
   
    
    range_high_LDN := -100000.0
    range_low_LDN := 99999999.9

//Code for drawing Top and Bottom Range AM Session
if isOnStart_AM
    startIDX_AM:=bar_index

if isInRange_AM
    line.new(startIDX_AM,close,startIDX_AM,close,extend = extend.both,color=colorSession)
    if not close_to_close
        range_high_AM := math.max(range_high_AM, high)
        range_low_AM:= math.min(range_low_AM, low)
    
    if close_to_close
        range_high_AM := math.max(range_high_AM, close)
        range_low_AM:= math.min(range_low_AM, close)
    distance_AM := range_high_AM - range_low_AM

    if Equilibrium
        range_mid_AM := range_high_AM - distance_AM/2

if isOnEnd_AM
    line.new(startIDX_AM, range_mid_AM, bar_index, range_mid_AM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_dotted, color=colorMid,width =2)
    line.new(startIDX_AM, range_high_AM, bar_index, range_high_AM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorTop,width =2)
    var label_AM_High = label.new(bar_index,range_high_AM,text="BSL AM",textcolor=colorTop,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_AM_High,(startIDX_AM+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_AM_High,range_high_AM)
    label.set_size(label_AM_High,size.normal)
    line.new(startIDX_AM, range_low_AM, bar_index, range_low_AM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorBottom,width =2)
    var label_AM_Low = label.new(bar_index,range_low_AM,text="SSL AM",textcolor=colorBottom,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_AM_Low,(startIDX_AM+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_AM_Low,range_low_AM)
    label.set_size(label_AM_Low,size.normal)

    range_high_AM := -100000.0
    range_low_AM := 99999999.9

//Code for drawing Top and Bottom Range Lunch Session
if isOnStart_Lunch
    startIDX_Lunch:=bar_index

if isInRange_Lunch
    line.new(startIDX_Lunch,close,startIDX_Lunch,close,extend = extend.both,color=colorSession)
    if not close_to_close
        range_high_Lunch := math.max(range_high_Lunch, high)
        range_low_Lunch:= math.min(range_low_Lunch, low)
    
    if close_to_close
        range_high_Lunch := math.max(range_high_Lunch, close)
        range_low_Lunch:= math.min(range_low_Lunch, close)
    distance_Lunch := range_high_Lunch - range_low_Lunch

    if Equilibrium
        range_mid_Lunch := range_high_Lunch - distance_Lunch/2

if isOnEnd_Lunch
    line.new(startIDX_Lunch, range_mid_Lunch, bar_index, range_mid_Lunch, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_dotted, color=colorMid,width =2)
    line.new(startIDX_Lunch, range_high_Lunch, bar_index, range_high_Lunch, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorTop,width =2)
    var label_Lunch_High = label.new(bar_index,range_high_Lunch,text="BSL Lunch",textcolor=colorTop,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_Lunch_High,(startIDX_Lunch+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_Lunch_High,range_high_Lunch)
    label.set_size(label_Lunch_High,size.normal)
    line.new(startIDX_Lunch, range_low_Lunch, bar_index, range_low_Lunch, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorBottom,width =2)
    var label_Lunch_Low = label.new(bar_index,range_low_Lunch,text="SSL Lunch",textcolor=colorBottom,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_Lunch_Low,(startIDX_Lunch+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_Lunch_Low,range_low_Lunch)
    label.set_size(label_Lunch_Low,size.normal)

    range_high_Lunch := -100000.0
    range_low_Lunch := 99999999.9

//Code for drawing Top and Bottom Range PM Session
if isOnStart_PM
    startIDX_PM:=bar_index

if isInRange_PM
    line.new(startIDX_PM,close,startIDX_PM,close,extend = extend.both,color=colorSession)
    if not close_to_close
        range_high_PM := math.max(range_high_PM, high)
        range_low_PM:= math.min(range_low_PM, low)
    
    if close_to_close
        range_high_PM := math.max(range_high_PM, close)
        range_low_PM:= math.min(range_low_PM, close)
    distance_PM := range_high_PM - range_low_PM

    if Equilibrium
        range_mid_PM := range_high_PM - distance_PM/2


if isOnEnd_PM
    line.new(startIDX_PM, range_mid_PM, bar_index, range_mid_PM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_dotted, color=colorMid,width =2)
    line.new(startIDX_PM, range_high_PM, bar_index, range_high_PM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorTop,width =2)
    var label_PM_High = label.new(bar_index,range_high_PM,text="BSL PM",textcolor=colorTop,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_PM_High,(startIDX_PM+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_PM_High,range_high_PM)
    label.set_size(label_PM_High,size.normal)
    line.new(startIDX_PM, range_low_PM, bar_index, range_low_PM, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid, color=colorBottom,width =2)
    var label_PM_Low = label.new(bar_index,range_low_PM,text="SSL PM",textcolor=colorBottom,style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label_PM_Low,(startIDX_PM+bar_index)/2) 
    label.set_y(label_PM_Low,range_low_PM)
    label.set_size(label_PM_Low,size.normal)
    
    range_high_PM := -100000.0
    range_low_PM := 99999999.9
```

I have tried to change the max_bars_back but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing multiple lines on each candle. They are overlapping and you do not have unlimited lines. You should delete the lines you don't use.

Use [line.delete](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line.delete)

Something like this:

```
if isInRange_AM
    l_isInRange_AM = line.new(startIDX_AM,close,startIDX_AM,close,extend = extend.both,color=colorSession)
    if not close_to_close
        range_high_AM := math.max(range_high_AM, high)
        range_low_AM:= math.min(range_low_AM, low)
    
    if close_to_close
        range_high_AM := math.max(range_high_AM, close)
        range_low_AM:= math.min(range_low_AM, close)
    distance_AM := range_high_AM - range_low_AM

    if Equilibrium
        range_mid_AM := range_high_AM - distance_AM/2


    if isInRange_AM[1]
        line.delete(l_isInRange_AM)
```